# Ruby loop outputs duplicates

Tags: ruby, loops

How can the duplicates from this code output be stopped.

```
RE = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/
TAG_RE = /<(.+?)>(.*?)<.+?>/

text = "<date>show</date> me the current conditions for <city> detroit <END>"
a = []

text.scan(TAG_RE).map { |w| a<< w; }

text.gsub(RE, '').split.each do |q|
    a.each_with_index do |v, i|
        if q == a[i].last.strip
            puts "#{q}\tB-#{a[i].first}"        
        else
            puts "#{q}\tO"          
        end

    end
end
```

OUTPUTS

```
show    B-date
show    O
me  O
me  O
the O
the O
current O
current O
conditions  O
conditions  O
for O
for O
detroit O
detroit B-city
```

I just want single instances of the word if they match condition

Like this

```
show    B-date
me  O
the  O
current   O
conditions   O
for  O
detroit B-city
```

Where can I put the `next` in the loop?

EDIT
Is this code *Rubyiotic?*

```
text.gsub(RE, '').split.each do |q|
    a.each_with_index do |v, i|
        @a = a[i].last.strip # save in a variable    
        if @a == q
            puts "#{q}\tB-#{a[i].first}"    
            break # break inner loop if match found
        end
    end
    next if @a == q #skip current outer loop if match found
    puts "#{q}\tO"  
end
```

Comment: Should detroit have a closing `</city>` tag?

Comment: That wont matter. It just check for words enclosed within tags and then gets the tag name from the beginning part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're also iterating over your `a` which is actually a hash between tags and words.

If you treat your `scan` a `hash` instead of an `array`, then you don't get duplicates.

```
RE = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/
TAG_RE = /<(.+?)>(.*?)<.+?>/

text = "<date>show</date> me the current conditions for <city> detroit <END>"

a = text.scan(TAG_RE)

text.gsub(RE, '').split.each do |q|
  d = a.find { |p| p.last.strip == q }
  if d
    puts "#{q}\tB-#{d.first}"
  else
    puts "#{q}\tO"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
show    B-date
me      O
the     O
current O
conditions      O
for     O
detroit B-city
```

And, while we're at it, you can use a proper `hash`:

```
RE = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/
TAG_RE = /<(.+?)>(.*?)<.+?>/

text = "<date>show</date> me the current conditions for <city> detroit <END>"

map = Hash[*text.scan(TAG_RE).flatten.map(&:strip)].invert

text.gsub(RE, '').split.each do |q|
  tag = map[q]
  if tag
    puts "#{q}\tB-#{tag}"
  else
    puts "#{q}\tO"
  end
end
```

Which generates the same output.

EDIT:
If you're wondering on a more Ruby-*esque* way, I would probably do something like this:

```
class Text
  TAGS_RE = /<("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/
  TAGS_WORDS_RE = /<(.+?)>\s*(.*?)\s*<.+?>/

  def self.strip_tags(text)
    text.gsub(TAGS_RE, '')
  end

  def self.tagged_words(text)
    matches = text.scan(TAGS_WORDS_RE)
    Hash[*matches.flatten].invert
  end
end

class Word
  def self.display(word, tag)
    puts "#{word}\t#{Word.tag(tag)}"
  end

  private

  def self.tag(tag)
    tag ? "B-#{tag}" : "0"
  end
end

text = "<date>show</date> me the current conditions for <city> detroit <END>"

words_tag = Text.tagged_words(text)
Text.strip_tags(text).split.each do |word|
  tag = words_tag[word]
  Word.display(word, tag)
end
```

Why?

I'm not that smart and I'm very lazy, so I prefer to write things as explicit as possible. So, I try to avoid cycles as much as possible.

Writing a loop is easy, but reading a loop is not as easy because you have to keep the context of what you read while you keep on reading and parsing the source code.

Usually, cycles with `break`s and `next`s are even harder to parse since you have to keep track on what code paths abruptly ends the cycle.

Nested cycles are even harder because you have to keep track of more than one context that changes at different speeds.

I believe that the proposed version is easier to read because each line can be understood on it's own. There is very little context that we have to remember while going from one line to the next.

Details are abstracted in methods, so if you just want to understand the big picture, you can look at the main part of the code:

```
words_tag = Text.tagged_words(text)
Text.strip_tags(text).split.each do |word|
  tag = words_tag[word]
  Word.display(word, tag)
end
```

And if you want to understand the details on how it's done, you look at how the methods are implemented. With this approach, implementation details are not leaked to places where they might not be needed.

I think this is a good practice in every programming language, not just in Ruby.

Comment: Heya. I made an edit to the question. I used `break` and `next`. Good ruby? _BTW, your code has good taste. Of course should have thought of `Hash` ;)._

Comment: Thanks :). I updated the answer to address your new question.